# how to get 2 databases with different tables

Tags: php, mysql

This is driving me crazy. How can I display profile page when my login information is in another database and my profile information is in a different database and table how can I link these 2 tables so I can retrieve profile information.

I tried submitting the email address when profile information was being submitted but that didn't work here is what I used:

```
<?php

  include('stuff.php');

  $email=$_GET['email'];
  $tbl_name1="table";

  $sql1="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name1 WHERE email ='$email'";
  $result1=mysql_query($sql1);

  // If successfully queried 
  if($result1){
     $count=mysql_num_rows($result1);

     if($count==1){
         $rows=mysql_fetch_array($result1);
         $email=$rows['email'];
         include('con.php');
         $tbl_name2="members";
         $sql2="INSERT INTO $tbl_name2(email)VALUES('$email')";
         $result2=mysql_query($sql2);

?>
```

Please help me this website has been really difficult to make by myself.

Answer (score 1):

You can do queries across multiple databases ( but on the same server) in MySQL. 
For example:

```
SELECT * FROM database1.table1 
JOIN database2.table2 ON table2.table1_id = table1.id
WHERE table1.user_id = 666
```

Comment: The OP will need to ensure their credentials are valid for both databases too.

Comment: What of I don't know the id?

Comment: `id` is just an example. You can use any other condition for `JOIN`. How would you design that query if tables were in the same database ( because it was the only problem, that you described)? Then do it the same with database names added to table names.

Comment: Or I could also ask "how do you know that a user row from table1 matches the user profile from table2?" The answer is your condition for JOIN